# How to make relationships between already created nodes of different columns from a single csv file?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a **single** csv file whose contents are as follows -

```
id,name,country,level
1,jon,USA,international
2,don,USA,national
3,ron,USA,local
4,bon,IND,national
5,kon,IND,national
6,jen,IND,local
7,ken,IND,international
8,ben,GB,local
9,den,GB,international
10,lin,GB,national
11,min,AU,national
12,win,AU,local
13,kin,AU,international
14,bin,AU,international
15,nin,CN,national
16,con,CN,local
17,eon,CN,international
18,fon,CN,international
19,pon,SZN,national
20,zon,SZN,international
```

First of all I created a constraint on `id`

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT idConstraint ON (n:Name) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE
```

Then I created nodes for `name`, then for `country` and finally for `level` as follows -

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///demo.csv" AS row
MERGE (name:Name {name: row.name, id: row.id, country:row.country, level:row.level})
MERGE (country:Country {name: row.country})
MERGE (level:Level {type: row.level})
```

I can see the nodes fine. However, I want to be able to query for things like, for a given country how many names are there? For a given level, how many countries and then how many names for that country are there?

So for that I need to make Relationships between the nodes.
For that I tried like this -

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///demo.csv" AS row
MATCH (n:Name {name:row.name}), (c:Country {name:row.country}) 
CREATE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(c)
RETURN n,c
```

However this gives me a warning as follows -

```
This query builds a cartesian product between disconnected patterns.
If a part of a query contains multiple disconnected patterns, this will build a cartesian product between all those parts. This may produce a large amount of data and slow down query processing. While occasionally intended, it may often be possible to reformulate the query that avoids the use of this cross product, perhaps by adding a relationship between the different parts or by using OPTIONAL MATCH (identifier is: (c))
```

Moreover the resulting Graph looks slightly wrong - each Name node has 2 relations with a country whereas I would think there would be only one?
[image: graph]

I also have a nagging fear that I am not doing things in an optimized or correct way. This is just a demo. In my real dataset, I often cannot run multiple CREATE or MERGE statements together. I have to LOAD the same CSV file again and again to do pretty much everything from creating nodes. When creating relationships, because a cartesian product forms, the command basically gives Java Heap Memory error.

PS. I just started with neo4j yesterday. I really don't know much about it. I have been struggling with this for a whole day, hence thought of asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore the cartesian product warning, since that exact approach is needed in order to create the relationships that form the patterns you need.

As for the multiple relationships, it's possible you may have run the query twice. The second run would have created the duplicate relationships. You could use MERGE instead of CREATE for the relationships, that would ensure that there would be no duplicates.

Comment: You are right! I cleared everything and tried it again, and it worked. However, I have a question...is this the correct approach to go about doing what I want? I mean, given that everything is from a single csv file, creating these kinds of relationships...is there a better or simpler way?

Comment: It's the right approach: MATCH on the nodes you want to connect, then CREATE or MERGE the pattern between them. If you don't need to visually confirm, then you can omit the RETURN.

Comment: I think what I have done is completely wrong. not sure why it worked before but when I run it again I don't see any connections anymore. Specifically, I think the MATCH command for making relationships should be `MATCH (n:Name {country:row.country}), (c:Country {name:row.country})` not what I have mentioned right? I mean the idea is that you get the Name nodes and Country nodes where the country property of Name matches the name property of Country....earlier I was blindly taking all the names and all the countries. I am back to square 0, any suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: Either should work. Remember that when processing a CSV, the `row` means you're processing the info per row. So before, for the row, you matched to a person by name, and a country by the country name, and merged or created the relationship between them, that's a good approach. Your new Cypher here is matching on a name by its country property, and a country by its country property, that should work too, even outside of a LOAD CSV. That it's not working either means there's a typo, or data wasn't loaded correctly (extra whitespace?) or some mismatch. You should double-check your data.

Comment: Both the thought processes are correct. I refreshed everything and redid it and it worked.